# Mysqli fetch_assoc first result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a fetch_assoc query that will grab 14 rows, but I want the FIRST result displayed so it is differnet to the others, then the rest are just ordinary.

```
    $site_events = $db->query("SELECT * FROM site_events ORDER BY time ASC limit 14");
        while($events = $site_events->fetch_assoc()) {

        if( first result???? ) { //this is where im stuck
           echo $events['title'], 'FIRST RESULT';
        }

        //then display others like a normal list..
        echo $events['title'], '<br />';
   }
```

Comment: you can always use a *variable* to store the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch first line outside the "while" and then continue normally. But first you should probably check if there are data selected just in case:

```
$site_events = $db->query("SELECT * FROM site_events ORDER BY time ASC limit 14");
if($db->field_count){
   $event = $site_events->fetch_assoc();
   echo $event['title'], 'FIRST RESULT';

   while($events = $site_events->fetch_assoc()) {

     //then display others like a normal list..
     echo $events['title'], '<br />';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I based mine on Yatin Trivedi's answer, but removed the increment with a variable which I unset. You wont notice the difference, but this is a bit faster. This is because the `$i++` doens't have to be called every itteration. Also, `unset()` is really fast.
Edit: That answer started with `$i=0` and a `$i++`, now it doesnt anymore :)

```
$hasNotLooped = true; // set it before you run the loop
$site_events = $db->query("SELECT * FROM site_events ORDER BY time ASC limit 14");
    while($events = $site_events->fetch_assoc()) {

    if( $hasNotLooped ) {
       echo $events['title'], 'FIRST RESULT';
       unset($hasNotLooped);
    }
    //then display others like a normal list..
    echo $events['title'], '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Why not just `if ($hasNotLooped) $hasNotLooped = false;`?

Comment: Doesnt really matter I guess... Either way has advantages. You could say I just removed some info from the memory

Comment: Is it possible to make it so the first results inst duplicated again? Cause its duplicated and echos like a normal one as well.

Comment: Just wrap it with an `else{}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp=true;
$site_events = $db->query("SELECT * FROM site_events ORDER BY time ASC limit 14");
    while($events = $site_events->fetch_assoc()) {

    if( $tmp) { //this is where im stuck
       echo $events['title'], 'FIRST RESULT';
       $tmp=false;
    }
    else
    {
    //then display others like a normal list..
    echo $events['title'], '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Booleans are quicker than integers. Just saying.

Comment: you could improve speed by adding the $tmp++ in the if statement... (microscopical difference :) )

Comment: Is it possible to make it so the first results inst duplicated again? Cause its duplicated and echos like a normal one as well.